# How to get PlaceMark title to be shown by default in map view?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I am able to place the PlaceMark on the MapView however I have to click on the pin to be able to see the title come up. What I want is the title to be shown by default.

Here is my code so far:

```
  [self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];

    PlaceMark *placeMark = [[PlaceMark alloc]
                            initWithCoordinate:self.centerOfMap
                            andMarkTitle:@"My Title"
                            andMarkSubTitle:@"Sub Title"];


    [self.mapView addAnnotation:placeMark];
```

Also:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[PlaceMark class]]) {

        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

        return annotationView;
    }

    return nil; 
}
```

Comment: The answers from [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=selectannotation+didaddannotationviews) have what you need (use selectAnnotation).

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at overlay delegate.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{


}
```

Comment: I have updated my code above to show my implementation. I still am unable to see the title by default.

Comment: do you see annotation on the map?

Comment: yes I do. I just want the annootation to also show the title by default as if it was clicked.